# Practical way to use DocPad for a site with multiple landing pages

Tags: coffeescript, web-hosting, docpad

I would like to use DocPad together with its built-in server.

For a website with a single landing page I have set up the structure as recommended on DocPad website: all page sources go into the `src/documents`, static files into `src/files` and layouts for the page sources into `src/layouts`. Then `docpad run` will generate the resulting site in the `out` directory and launch a web server using which I can inspect the current state in my browser.

Now, I would like to do the same with multiple landing pages. That means, I plan to deploy files to one site, `http://site-one.org` and other files to another site `http://site-two.org`. I am doing this by deploying web pages to two distinct directories `/public/site-one/` and `/public/site-two/` at my web hoster.

What is the most practical way to accomplish this with DocPad?

These are the things I have tried so far -- they both work (sort of), but neither is very elegant:

1. Let page sources go into `src/documents/site-one` and `src/documents/site-two` and static files into `src/files/site-one` and `src/files/site-two`. This renders the entire site properly and it can be uploaded easily. However, the entire DocPad infrastructure with live-reload and the built-in server no longer works (since the built-in server root directory points to `out/` instead of `out/site-[one|two]/` as it should).
2. Have two separate DocPad-installations with duplicate `docpad.coffee` files, duplicate plugins and partially duplicate `src/*` trees and then upload the resulting `out` tree to the corresponding sub-directory on the server.

**Update:** When using option 1, instead of using DocPad built-in live-reload feature it's possible to use one's own web server, point it to `out/site-one` on one port and `out/site-two` on another port and then use the grunt live-reload feature which is part of [grunt-contrib-watch](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch#optionslivereload), where grunt is available as a plugin [here](https://github.com/RobLoach/docpad-plugin-grunt). It requires adding a single line of code to the template file, see [this link](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch/blob/master/docs/watch-examples.md#enabling-live-reload-in-your-html), and to configure the plugin, see [this link](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch#live-reloading).

**Update 2:** A possible solution would involve the ability to set a custom directory for the server. By default it is set to the `out` directory. While that can be changed, it is not possible to specify separate directories for the `generate` action and the `watch` action. However, I have not found such an option in the configuration files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this is much easier than I thought. DocPad has a scarcely documented feature called "environments". This allows to customize several of the regular configuration variables, making it easy to pick the desired landing page on the command line.

This [blog post on multiple languages](http://blog.sapegin.me/all/multilingual-docpad) demonstrates exactly how to customize both the document and the output paths in different environments. Applied to my original problem it becomes:

```
docpadConfig = {
    ...
    environments:
        site-one:
            documentsPaths: ['documents_site-one']
            outPath: 'out_site-one'
        site-two:
            documentsPaths: ['documents_site-two']
            outPath: 'out_site-two'
    ...
}
```

Then it is as simple as

```
docpad [generate|run|...] --env [site-one|site-two|...]
```

to run regular commands like `generate` etc. for one of the landing pages by picking the proper custom environment.